# How to return images with FastAPI via AWS Lambda and AWS APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I am really struggeling with FastAPI + AWS Lambda + AWS APIGateway to return an image. So actually I am using redis to catch up an image and want to return it via Rest-API. My expected output is an image. But actually I am receiving nothing.

So here is my FastAPI :

```py
""" tiny tileserver """
import redis
from datetime import datetime
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi import Query
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from mangum import Mangum
import base64

LOCAL_FILE_PATH = "/app/images"
REDIS_HOST = "XXX"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
DATE_TIME_PARSING_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_HEADER = {
    "Date": "-",
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Status": "200 OK",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Language": "en-US",
}

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["GET"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
)
redis = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)

handler = Mangum(app)


@app.get("/radar", tags=["radar"])
async def get_radar_tiles(
    dt: str = Query(
        ...,
        title="Timestamp",
        description="Timestamp has to be passed in ISO 8601 "
        "format in UTC. E.g.: "
        "2020-10-06T15:15:00 %Y-%m-%dT%H:%H:%S",
    ),
    x: int = Query(...),
    y: int = Query(...),
    z: int = Query(...),
):
    """API callback to return a single"""
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(dt, DATE_TIME_PARSING_FORMAT)
    target_key = f"{timestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}_" f"{z}_" f"{x}_" f"{y}.png"
    return Response(
        content=base64.b64encode(redis.get(target_key)),
        media_type="image/png",
        headers={'isBase64Encoded': "True"}
    )
```

The response from redis is a binary of a png image.

When I follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) guide, FastAPI or Mangun return a JSON instead of an image/png. The output will look like this:

```json
{"headers":{"Content-Type":"image/png"},"statusCode":200,"body":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAAABFUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVP7WsIoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAeAMBPAABPO1TCQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==","isBase64Encoded":true}
```

I have remove the `Response` by the suggested dictionary.

Here are my configurations in API Gateway and the response in chrome inspector:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any hint that will help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Lambda Proxy integration on your API gateway try the following steps:

- under AWS API gateway > Models > create a model name with ImagePNG
  and {} as model schema.
- under API gateway > Resources > your GET endpoint > click 'Method
  Response'. create new response status for 200. add new header
  'Content-Type' under 'Response Headers for 200'. add 'Response Body
  for 200' as 'image/png' and select ImagePNG as modal you previously created.
- under API gateway > Settings > 'Binary Media Types' add 'image/png' and 'text/html' as supported binary type.'text/html' is required if you are accessing directly via browser.
  (otherwise, it should work if you send the 'Accept' header as
  'image/png'). If that didn't work add `*/*` as binary media type to
  allow all types.